# Simplification of complex number factors out an extra i

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

When I evaluate

```
Simplify[ - a - I Sqrt[3] a - b - I Sqrt[3] b ]
```

Mathematica returns

```
-I (-I + Sqrt[3]) (a + b)
```

Personally, I find it annoying that it factors out an extra `I` since it doesn't make the expression simpler (and I think in this case it is unambiguous that `(- 1 - I Sqrt[3]) (a + b)` is actually simpler...). `FullSimplify` does the same. For 1 complex number, I could use `Expand` but for expressions with variables this screws up the simplification.

Why does Mathematica do this and is there an easy way to get rid of these extra factors of `I`?

Comment: `FullSimplify[-a - I Sqrt[3] a - b - I Sqrt[3] b]` gives what you want:  `(-1 - I Sqrt[3]) (a + b)`  (Mathematica v12.2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`FullSimplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) and restrict the [`ComplexityFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction.html) to only look at the [`LeafCount`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LeafCount.html)

```
FullSimplify[-a - I Sqrt[3] a - b - I Sqrt[3] b, 
 ComplexityFunction -> LeafCount]

(* (-1 - I Sqrt[3]) (a + b) *)
```

Answer (score 1):

For the complex expressions, one has to use `ComplexExpand` and combine it with `Simplify` or other functions if necessary. For example, for your expression

```
expr1 = -a - I Sqrt[3] a - b - I Sqrt[3] b;
```

the application of the `ComplexExpand` returns the following:

```
expr2 = ComplexExpand[expr1]

(*  -a - b + I (-Sqrt[3] a - Sqrt[3] b)  *)
```

Then one can do, for example, this:

```
MapAt[Factor, expr2, 3]

(*  -a - b - I Sqrt[3] (a + b)  *)
```

Or something else.

On the other hand, one can apply the replacement `a+b->x`, then simplify and replace back:

```
(expr1 /. a -> x - b // Simplify) /. x -> a + b

(*   (-1 - I Sqrt[3]) (a + b)  *)
```

One can go also this way:

```
(ComplexExpand[(expr1 // Simplify) /. a -> x - b] // Simplify) /. 
 x -> a + b

(* (-1 - I Sqrt[3]) (a + b)  *)
```

Many ways lead to a correct answer.

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Building a small `SimplifyComplex` function:

```
 SimplifyComplex[expr_, assumptions___] := 
 If[NumericQ[expr] === True, 
 Plus[Factor@
 Part[Refine[Map[ComplexExpand, {FullSimplify[Re[expr]]}]], 1], 
 I*Factor@
 Part[Refine[Map[ComplexExpand, {FullSimplify[Im[expr]]}]], 1]], 
 Plus[Factor@
 Part[Refine[Map[ComplexExpand, {FullSimplify[Re[expr]]}], 
 Assumptions -> assumptions], 1], 
 I*Factor@
 Part[Refine[Map[ComplexExpand, {FullSimplify[Im[expr]]}], 
 Assumptions -> assumptions], 1]]]
```

Test 1:

```
SimplifyComplex[-a - I Sqrt[3] a - b - I Sqrt[3] b, {a, b} \[Element] Reals]
(*-a - b - I Sqrt[3] (a + b)*)
```

Test 2:

```
SimplifyComplex[(a - b I)/(c + d I), {a, b, c, d} \[Element] Reals]
(*-((I (b c + a d))/(c^2 + d^2)) + (a c - b d)/(c^2 + d^2)*)
```

Test 3:

```
SimplifyComplex[(1 - 2 I)/(3 + 2 I)]
(*-(1/13) - (8 I)/13*)
```